# Several warnings when building Opencv with CMake on Windows

Tags: opencv, cmake, gpu, cudnn

I'm following some tutorials to build OpenCV with Cuda support, but when i build it, it shows hundreds of warning messages about OpenCV_world. I've tried different OpenCV versions, like 4.5.5 and 4.5.1, and both of them get the same warning.[Warning messages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3LAq6.png)

My CMake configuration is the default as the most tutorial guide videos like [this one](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YsmhKar8oOc&t=503s).Also my cuda and cudnn versions are the latest one released.

I want to use GPU for yolo, so as far as i searched, opencv_world module is important to achieve this

Update:

Apparently my cmake isn't generating opencv_world.lib even when activate manually this option.

[opencv_world.lib missing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HcPW4.png)
[CMake build Opencv_world](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AgEwT.png)

But i have no idea what is preventing it from build it.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Here we expect the **question post** to contain all relevant information, and preferably in a textual form (not images or videos). Please, read [ask] and [edit] the question post accordingly.

Comment: "I want to use GPU for yolo" -- please clarify if you want to use darknet or opencv's dnn

Comment: so you installed cuda firstly and following by installi,g opencv with cuda support ?